# insert or update confusion

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm a bit confused about how to handle the situation where you update a row in sqlite if it exists, or insert it if it doesn't. I seem to see a different solution on every answer there is to this problem. Whats the most efficient or easiest way?
EDIT: I meant sqlite, sorry

Answer (score 3):

**For sqlite:**

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar INTEGER UNIQUE, baz INTEGER)
INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (1, 2)
```

This should cause an IntegrityError: column bar is not unique:

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (1,3)
```

But with sqlite you can [upsert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsert) by doing [INSERT OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html):

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO foo (bar,baz) VALUES (1,3)
```

Instead of inserting a new row, since a row with bar equaling 1 already exists, the value of baz is updated to 3.

---

**For MySQL:**

Create a UNIQUE index on the table.
Then use

```
INSERT INTO table (...) values (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field = ...
```

for example:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX mytable_index ON mytable (field1,field2)

INSERT INTO mytable (field1,field2,field3) values (val1,val2,val3) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field3 = val3
```

This requires that (field1,field2) pairs in mytable be unique.
Then when you insert, either you will get a new row, or, if (val1,val2) already exist in `mytable`, the value of field3 will be updated.

Comment: I like the word "UPSERT", they should make it a standard SQL command. UPSERT INTO foo ...

Answer (score 0):

IF EXISTS may be helpful here, having you update if the condition yields true or insert if false.